# How I Remove Log i error

Tags: java, android

This is my `MainActivity.java`. This what I tried . But Its giving an error.

```
     package com.funbegins;

     import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;

     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
     import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn_go=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn_go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              Log.i("clicks","You Clicked B1");
          Intent i=new Intent(
                 MainActivity.this,
                 MainActivity2.class);
          startActivity(i);
        }
        }
        });
     }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

And this the error I am getting

```
`onClick(View)- The method e(String, String) is undefined for the type Log`
```

I also tried to define the strings for clicks and message like this

```
    String clicks="clicks";
    String message="You Clicked B!1";
    Log.i(clicks,message);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: import `android.util.Log` instead of `org.apache.commons.logging.Log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change import statement

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
```

with

```
import android.util.Log;
```

You need to import `android.util.Log` into Android.

Answer (score 1):

This is because may be you have imported any library project or any jar file which contains class named ***Log*** and that's why you had imported that Log by.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
```

So its give you error.

So you must use ***android.util.Log*** of android system.

So import your Log as

```
import android.util.Log;
```

instead of

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
```